# Can anyone spot the issue with this VB.Net code?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, factory-method

I'm writing some code in VB.Net which I hope demonstrate to colleagues (not to say familiarise myself a little more) with various design patterns - and I'm having an issue with the FactoryMethod Pattern.

Here's my code:

```
Namespace Patterns.Creational.FactoryMethod

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is the Factory bit - the other classes are merely by way of an example...
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class CarFactory
        ''' <summary>
        ''' CreateCar could have been declared as Shared (in other words,a Class method) - it doesn't really matter.
        ''' Don't worry too much about the contents of the CreateCar method - the point is that it decides which type
        ''' of car should be created, and then returns a new instance of that specific subclass of Car.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Function CreateCar() As Car
            Dim blnMondeoCondition As Boolean = False
            Dim blnFocusCondition As Boolean = False
            Dim blnFiestaCondition As Boolean = False

            If blnMondeoCondition Then
                Return New Mondeo()
            ElseIf blnFocusCondition Then
                Return New Focus()
            ElseIf blnFiestaCondition Then
                Return New Fiesta()
            Else
                Throw New ApplicationException("Unable to create a car...")
            End If

        End Function
    End Class

    Public MustInherit Class Car
        Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Price() As Decimal
    End Class

    Public Class Mondeo Inherits Car

        Public ReadOnly Overrides Property Price() As Decimal
            Get
                Return 17000
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class

    Public Class Focus Inherits Car
        Public ReadOnly Overrides Property Price() As Decimal
            Get
                Return 14000
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class

    Public Class Fiesta Inherits Car
        Public ReadOnly Overrides Property Price() As Decimal
            Get
                Return 12000
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class

End Namespace
```

When I try to compile this, I am getting errors (BC30311) in the CarFactory.CreateCar telling me that it can't convert Fiesta, Mondeo, and Focus into Car. I don't see what the issue is - they're all subclasses of Car.

Doubtless I'm overlooking something simple. Can anyone spot it?

Cheers,

Martin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Inherits keyword must be on a new line. This is documented by Microsoft on their help and Support. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307222

> Change the SavingsAccount class
>   definition as follows, so that
>   SavingsAccount inherits from Account
>   (note that the Inherits keyword must
>   appear on a new line):

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I knew it would be something I had overlooked. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Put `Inherits` on new line or use `:` to separate the class name and `Inherits` statement:

```
Public Class Mondeo
    Inherits Car
...


Public Class Focus
    Inherits Car
...


Public Class Fiesta
    Inherits Car
...
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for that... Most of my experience with DotNet is in C#, so I thought it would most likely be a syntax issue.

Answer (score 1):

The first error in the list is just the one at the lowest line number, it's not always the actual cause of the error.

Further down in the list of errors you will see (among several others) three more errors saying `End of statement expected.` at each of the subclasses. This is beacuse `Class` and `Inherits` are separate statements and go on separate lines:

```
Public Class Mondeo
  Inherits Car
```

or:

```
Public Class Mondeo : Inherits Car
```

When you fix these errors, the classes do actually inherit from `Car`, and your code works.